# Script to get specific DB Size and details

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using the powershell script below to get size and details information of a Microsoft SQLServer Database.

Could anyone advise on how to get just the databases which start with or contain specific text like "xyz"?

I tried to use the command below but it didn't work:

```
if 
Sdbs -contains "xyz"
{ Do Task}
```

SCRIPT:

```
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "D:\SQL_Servers.txt")
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
     $s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $instance
     $dbs=$s.Databases       
     $dbs | SELECT Name, Collation, CompatibilityLevel, AutoShrink, RecoveryModel, Size, SpaceAvailable
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a where clause to your code:

```
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "D:\SQL_Servers.txt")
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
     $s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $instance
     $dbs=$s.Databases       
     $dbs | WHERE {$_.Name.Contains("xyz")} | SELECT Name, Collation, CompatibilityLevel, AutoShrink, RecoveryModel, Size, SpaceAvailable
}
```

Comment: @AD41285: Would you please upvote this answer? I would upvote your question too.